# A Conditional Probability Question

Tags: multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability

Assume we know
$$p(w) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$$
$$p(e) \sim N(0, 0.01)$$
$$y=w^\intercal x$$
$$o = y + e$$

Where w/x/o/y/e are all vector

How do we calculate the distribution of
$$p(y|o,x)$$

Comment: This does not completely make sense. Assuming the "$p$" are extraneous symbols, so that we can ignore them, you seem to assert that $w$ has a multinormal distribution and $e$ has a *univariate* normal distribution. From the formula $y$ must be a *number* and so, therefore must $o$. I suspect you don't want $x$ to be a vector at all, but rather a matrix; and that you are asking for the posterior distribution of a response $y$ conditional on observing it with iid error, with a zero-mean multivariate normal prior on the regression coefficients.

Comment: Sorry my bad. P means the probability of w. e is also mutinormal maybe I should make it more clear (a vector of iid) @whuber

Comment: Yes, please edit it to clear up those issues.  The "$p$" notation is superfluous and potentially confusing.  When $w$ is a random variable, "$w\sim N(0,\Sigma)$" means that $w$ has a $N(0,\Sigma)$ distribution.